# How to Install single .msi file multiple times on same server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-deployment

We have a requirement i.e single .msi file need to be installed on the same server with different instances multiple times, but .msi file not allowing the user to install again if it is already installed on the server.

here I am using visual studio setup project installer. Can anyone please provide suggestions/approaches in order to achieve this.

Comment: Do you always have the same number of installations in the same paths? In this case you can probably modify the msi to copy the content to the respective targets in addition to what is put in the selected installation path.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Every msi has a package code that is used to identify that specific installer package and prevent installing the same package twice, so it is fundamentally not a designed-for scenario to install a single msi multiple times.